# Regex to replace namespace

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string

```
string s = "efile:ReturnState/efile:ReturnDataState/efile:processBO/composition/forms/IT204CP";
```

I would like to replace the `efile:` name space with an empty string and would like the result to be as follows

> "ReturnState/ReturnDataState/processBO/composition/forms/IT204CP";

I also would like to know if there is a more generic way of doing this, as in something where I can replace any namespace like we see above and not just `efile`?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is a real simple regex...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: http://regexr.com/3b8md

Comment: Just a guess but does your source XML (I'm assuming that is an xpath statement)  specify a default namespace but you have a bunch of xpath that binds that namespace to efile?

Comment: Thanks Bas, this is what i exactly wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Regex here; Regex is meant for pattern matching but you just need to replace a string literal with another one (empty string).

`s = s.Replace(@"efile:","")`

will remove all instances of `efile:`

if you want generic, then simply replace the "efile:" literal with a string variable and set the variable to whatever you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

As DeanOC mentioned, there's no need to use a regex for this, but if you really want to, the regex is really straightforward

```
string result = Regex.Replace(s, "efile:", "");
```